# How could a the global economy have no money/collapse?

Tags: economy, alternate-worlds, computers

I would like a plausible way to tank the world economy. I am trying to make a political horror world, that would be very different from today. The basis should be a lack of money or decreased value of money.

Can the world's money run out and cause economic collapse?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141288/discussion-on-question-by-pamv75-how-could-a-the-global-economy-have-no-money-co).

Comment: It's normal for the mods to push lengthy comment chains into chat - but the consequence is that all the clarifications you made might as well have been deleted. Please [edit] your post and add all the clarifications. (This is a very good habit to get into. Never trust that people will read through all the comments.)

Answer (score 2):

After clarification in the comments, what the question really wants is not to delete the money (which is not really something that can actually happen), but simply for the money to be gone. This *can* happen.

The perfect historical example is the effect of the [Great October Socialist Revolution which Took Place in November](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/October_Revolution). All the money in Russian banks was nationalized. Accounts denominated in Russian roubles held in foreign banks became worthless. Shares in Russian companies became worthless. Bonds of Russian companies and societies became worthless, including sovereign bonds of the Russian Empire itself. Basically, all accounts in Russian roubles worldwide, and all the securities denominated in Russian roubles, became worthless overnight.

There was no significant impact on world economy, because in 1918, just like today, Russia, although a large and powerful country, was dirt poor and represented only a tiny fraction of the world economy.

In today's world, just about all world economy is based on US dollars, and to a lesser extent on euros.

*If* you can arrange for successful Bolshevik revolutions in the USA and in the European Union, you can have all the US dollar and euro accounts and assets become worthless almost overnight.

The impact would be that the world economy stops dead. A very large fraction of the contracts that form the basis on which the worldwide economy works will become unenforceable. The globalized economy will suddenly break down into national economies. Some countries, for example the USA, Russia, and (depending on the exact scenario) the European Union, can survive for quite some time if forced to rely on their own internal production of food and fuel and steel and textiles etc. But some large countries, most notably China with its 1.4 billion people, cannot produce enough food and fuel to feed their population and keep them warm. Other countries at great risk include Japan, Malaysia, Indonesia, large parts of Africa, possibly India, and so on.

The point being that after the victory of the Euro-American Bolshevik Revolutions, you will have a world completely different from what we have today. Instead of an integrated world economy feeding and clothing 8 billion people, there will be a fragmented world, with many centers of power, all of them enemies of all the others. (For example, what do you think that the 1.4 billion people of China will do if the world economy goes belly up and they can no longer import food and fuel peacefully?)

Comment: AlexP it seems like currency/money doesn't have any value on its own, it seems to be determined by the government. On a partially related note (pun intended) does the susceptibility to government/politics of money mean that money has no inherent value? Like for example, I have a whole lot of us minted coins that are not collectable or gold/silver. It is about 10 dollars total. So then if the US government suddenly declared that it has no value, then it would lose all of its value? I learned in high school of fiat money, but I didn't think that usd bills and coins were fiat money.

Comment: Is usa personal currency just fiat money?

Comment: Well, the coins do have some small tiny value as metal. The value of the paper bills as paper is negligible -- it is not even useful for writing on it. (And the value of money is not "determined by the government". It is determined by the market -- what are other people willing to sell you for one of those nice colorful pieces of paper. Yes, the answer if oversimplified. The European Central Bank cannot make euro bills worthless worldwide, they can only make them worthless in the EU; if people in Burkina Faso have some euro bills and continue to assign value to them, that's their business.)

Comment: Isn't this the plotline of Mr. Robot?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it is happening in the American economy as this is being written.

It's called 'Financialization of the Economy', and yes it is a real thing. Obama recognized it was happening, and warned against it.

It occurs when money is made from money, instead of by making things.

A huge portion of the American economy, GDP, and financial wealth comes from interest payments and the increasing value of investments (stocks, land, bank accounts, GIC's and mutual funds). The financial community is driving the wealth of the American economy. Banks pay interest on the deposits, these deposits are kept in the bank as an asset, which the bank uses to pay more interest. The bank accounts keep getting bigger and bigger, and the bank is using them to pay interest to make the accounts grow even faster.

Same with the stock market. Players bid up the cost of stocks, and the buyers use borrowed money to buy them. This drives their stock portfolio higher, and so they can borrow more money to buy more stocks.

The problem is, not a dime goes back to increasing production. In fact, companies close down production, so that the money they earn on investments looks really good when set against sales. Companies use their profits to buy back their stock, instead of using it to buy material and to build manufacturing capacity for their production lines. Profit ratios go through the roof the less the company makes. If you have no production expense, then all income is profit. The value of a company is no longer on the total value of the goods it produces, but on its investments and investment returns.

Caterpillar, for example, makes a substantial portion of its profits, not from building machines, but from licensing its name to other companies to put on their product. Without this licensing income, Caterpillar would be losing money. The bottom line is, Caterpillar can make more money by licensing its name instead of making anything. Making machines has a cost side - raw materials, labor, factory and plant upkeep. To lower the overhead to zero, they stop making anything. All their profit comes from their investments in other stock, and on their brand. In point of fact, most of the yesteryear great American corporations have no manufacturing capacity. The goods that have their name on it are all manufactured by other companies. Their only asset is the brand, and their stockholders love it. Pure profit.

All of Tesla's profits come from tax incentives and rebates, not from selling vehicles. They actually sell the cars at a loss, but make up for it on the tax incentives.

Apple makes more money from their foreign investments than they do on selling products. Because they can not bring their profits back to America, they invest the overseas profits oversees, and declare the investment income on their balance sheets. The money wealth itself never comes back to America, never contributes to a single American manufacturing job.

Eventually, like what is happening in America, nothing is actually produced. The American government wants to increase exports, but the country makes nothing to export. They want China to buy more American 'stuff', and China would love to buy it, but there is nothing available in America for the Chinese to buy. All of the American manufacturing plants have shut down. They balance their foreign exchange through the income they get from oversees investments and financial services. The country 'charges' for other countries to use the greenback (through financialization), and this has become the prime basis for balancing their payments.

When the economy becomes fully financialized, all income comes from investments and from money, nothing comes from making goods.

The end result is that the rich become richer on fake money, and the poor have nothing to buy even if they could. There are no goods on the store shelves. The rich are buying whatever is available.

Eventually, you have an economy that looks very, very rich on paper, on the balance sheet, but there are no goods to be had. No one is producing anything.

You can have lots and lots of 'balance sheet' wealth, that can be used for further investments, to buy stocks, and to pay interest, but it is all useless when it comes to actually buying **things** instead of **more money**.

There is no lack of money per say, money has not 'run out', but there is a lack of **useful** money. Money is not **useful** if there is nothing to buy with it.

**TL:DR**

The trick is not to make money 'go away', the trick is to stop using money to make things. To stop investing in manufacturing plant, and instead investing in investment documents. Sell stocks, not things. Make your money by renting the same thing forever, not by selling new product.

The end result is that all of the available 'wealth' is in the hands of or controlled by  a few, absolutely unavailable to the average person. As far as the average person is concerned, there is no money. It has all disappeared. It is all just a number on a spreadsheet. There is no real wealth, no goods or product to be had, nothing physical of any value. Nothing is being made.

[Backgrounder](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/in-theory/wp/2016/04/18/has-our-economy-become-too-financialized/), from 2016. It is even worse now.

> Those worries could have merit. Over the past several decades, the
> financial sector has expanded to take up an extremely large slice of
> the U.S. economy, a trend referred to as “financialization.” In the
> United States, finance, insurance and real estate (known as FIRE) now
> account for 20 percent of gross domestic product, compared with only
> 10 percent in 1947. Financial institutions have significantly
> increased in scale and profitability relative to what most see as the
> “real” economy — the businesses that produce tangible goods — which
> has left the United States increasingly reliant on the financial
> sector to create overall economic growth.
>
> The imbalance is seen as problematic for a number of reasons. One is a
> lack of transparency: The financial sector’s complexity, resulting
> from an increased reliance on largely intangible assets without a
> fixed price, makes it opaque, impeding regulation and enabling
> information mismatches that allow insiders to profit at the expense of
> others. In 2013, one economist estimated that the compensation of
> financial intermediaries — the profits, wages, salaries and bonuses of
> the relatively small group of workers providing financial services —
> was 9 percent of GDP, an all-time high. Many would say that this has
> led directly to widening income inequality between a small pool of
> high earners and the rest of society, giving those earners ample
> reason and resources to sway government policy in their favor.
>
> Others argue that the financial sector is a self-inflating bubble,
> circulating credit and debt while diverting money that could be
> invested in a more stable manner and used to create more tangible
> goods. Indeed, some analysts estimate that only 15 percent of all the
> money in the market system ends up in the real economy, with most of
> it remaining in the closed loop of the financial sector.

[And](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/in-theory/wp/2016/04/22/how-the-rise-of-finance-has-warped-our-values/)

> The numbers are striking. Total shareholder payouts in 2014 exceeded USD 1.2 trillion
> an amount roughly in line with total corporate profits.
> This is the new normal: From the 1940s through the 1960s, closer to a
> quarter of profits went to shareholder payouts. During the mid-century
> period, companies borrowed to fund investments in research,
> infrastructure, technology and personnel. Now they borrow to fund
> buybacks and dividends. Finance used to be a way of getting money into
> our productive enterprises. Now it’s a tool for taking money out of
> them.
>
> This has serious macroeconomic consequences. There’s a lot of
> attention on the Verizon strike, but less attention to Verizon’s
> payouts to shareholders. Verizon did a USD 5 billion stock buyback last
> year to boost its stock price, on top of an already generous dividend.
> If that money had instead been divided among 180,000 workers, it would
> have come to USD 28,000 per person — showing that there’s plenty of
> profit to be shared across the company. Or, if it costs USD 500 to
> install FiOS in one household, that money could have been used to help
> 10 million households cross the digital divide. More generally, in a
> period with slack demand, low interest rates and high profits, we’d
> expect there to be more investment to take advantage of profitable
> opportunities, driving down those very profits. There is not, and the
> increasing power of finance has played a role in making this the case.

Comment: *"The country makes nothing to export":* The USA is the largest exporter of agricultural products in the entire world. It is the home of General Electric and Pratt & Whitney, two of the top three manufacturers of aircraft engines. It is the home of Boeing, one of the top two aircraft manufacturers. The USA is one of the world's top producers of integrated circuits. Dow Chemical is one of the top three chemical producers. Etc. Yes, it is true that the proportion of the workforce employed in manufacturing is decreasing, but that is normal for a developed country in the 21st century.

Comment: @AlexP
 And China's manufacturers make those companies look puny. The difference is America believes in gigagiantic  monopolies, one company makes everything, one company is all there is. China spreads the manufacturing over several companies, when combined are far bigger than the American behemoths. There is nothing America makes that China wants, except electronics and agricultural products, and America refuses to sell these to China. All of the companies you mentioned are downsizing, cutting production. If America did not produce weapons, America would produce nothing.

Comment: Look what happened to Ford and GM. They look big on paper, their vehicles and product are made offshore. And being 'the HOME' does not mean the manufacturing plant is in the country.

Comment: China has about four times more people than the USA, and the wages are still low enough to make manufacturing underwear and slippers profitable. But don't worry, the average pay is going up in China too, so that one can easily foresee that a lot of manufacturing will move somewhere else. Indonesia, Malaysia... Eventually, all countries with large workforces will become rich enough so that some manufacturing will come back to the USA. (And GM has dozens of factories in the USA. Or at least so says Wikipedia -- I don't know much about GM, as it basically is completely non-existant in Europe.)

Comment: That's the point. When China financializes their economy, followed by India (Europe has already deep in the process) who is left to produce anything? Gazillions of paper money, but no product. Money disappears, because the value disappears. It is just a figure on a spreadsheet. See https://www.cbsnews.com/news/gm-now-employs-more-workers-in-china-than-in-the-u-s/ regarding GM.